# Using DB::raw in POST request

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So I have a query that is selecting a table. That is all. This query runs in an AJAX POST request in one of my controllers. Here's the query:

```
$myTable = \DB::table('signature')
    ->where('email_list', 'LIKE', '%'.$request['email'].'%')
    ->select([
        'signature',
        'version',
        'type',
        DB::raw("CONCAT(signature.size,'',signature.size_unit) AS sizea")
    ])
    ->get();
echo json_encode($myTable, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Whenever I make the POST request, I get a error 500 Internal Server Error. If I remove/comment out the `DB::raw("CONCAT(signature.size,'',signature.size_unit) AS sizea")` part, the POST request goes through and everything is fine.

So there's probably something wrong with the `DB::raw` part, right? You'd think so, but if I use this query on the page I'm executing it on and `var_dump` it, the statement works, even with the `DB::raw` part.

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on?

EDIT: Error logs from Console:

```
POST                                                 jquery.min.js:4  
http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8000/lab/misc/signature/get_list 500 (Internal Server Error)
    send @ jquery.min.js:4
    ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
    (anonymous function) @ signature_hunter:345
    dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
    q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
    ListPicker._handleMouseUp @ about:blank:542
```

Comment: Check your error logs.

Comment: @aynber Added errors from console. They don't exactly tell me much..

Comment: No, sorry, I meant your server logs (apache or nginx) or your logs inside your storage folder (app/storage/logs or storage/logs, depending on your version of laravel)

Comment: +1 for reading `laravel.log` file. But I also think I recall something with this that I ran into as well...what if you move `signature`, `version`, `type` into the `DB::raw()`?

Comment: @aynber Wow I didn't know you could do this. This helps a lot. It turns out that I needed to add a ` \ ` in front of the `DB::raw` statement, as `'Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB'` wasn't found. This fixed it. Thanks!